# animate height content wont disappear

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

When I use this piece of code

```
$(function(){
  $('#myList').animate({
    height: '0px'
  }, 800);
}

<div id="myList">
  <h1 id="text"> Text Here </h1>
</div>
```

the div `#myList` will animate the height like expected, but `h1#text` will still be visible after the animation is finished.

How do I make it work so that when the height of `div#myList` gets so small that the content wont fit and will "disappear"?

Note: I just noticed that the h1 will "disappear" as the height gets animated like it should but it blinks and comes back when the function is finished.

Comment: is the div #myList set to `overflow:hidden;` in css?

Comment: works.. LOL. I can't believe I forgot about that :\

Comment: @lukasgeiter open up an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div `#myList` needs to be set `overflow:hidden;` in css.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function(){
  $('#myList').animate({
    height: '0px',
    overflow : 'hidden'
  }, 800);
}
```